# Custom button in adminhtml edit module

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, adminhtml

I have created a module to upload a csv  and create an import of custom data in it.
My form is well displayed and my custom button too. But when I click on the button nothing happens.

Any idea ?

app/code/Vendor/Branches/view/adminhtml/layout/branches_import_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>
        Branches
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Branches\Block\Adminhtml\Import\Edit" name="branches.import.form.container"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendor/Branches/Block/Adminhtml/Import/Edit.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Branches\Block\Adminhtml\Import;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{
/**
 * Internal constructor
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_objectId = 'branches_import_id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'Vendor_Branches';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_import';

    parent::_construct();
    $this->removeButton('back')->removeButton('reset')->removeButton('save');
    $this->buttonList->add(
        'branches_import',
        [
            'label' => __('Import Branches'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'button' => ['event' => 'save', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                ],
            ]
        ],
        1,
        10
    );
}

/**
 * Get header text
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getHeaderText()
{
    return __('Import');
}

/**
 * Check whether is allowed action
 *
 * @param string $resourceId
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
}
}
```

app/code/Vendor/Branches/Block/Adminhtml/Import/Edit/Form.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Branches\Block\Adminhtml\Import\Edit;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
/**
 * @var StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Export\FormatFactory
 */
protected $_formatFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
 * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Export\FormatFactory $formatFactory
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Export\FormatFactory $formatFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_formatFactory = $formatFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare form before rendering HTML.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        [
            'data' => [
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/import'),
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]
    );

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Import Settings')]);
    $fieldset->addField(
        'store',
        'select',
        [
            'name' => 'store',
            'title' => __('Store'),
            'label' => __('Store'),
            'required' => false,
            'values' => $this->getStoreData()
        ]
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::FIELD_NAME_SOURCE_FILE,
        'file',
        [
            'name' => \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::FIELD_NAME_SOURCE_FILE,
            'label' => __('Select File to Import'),
            'title' => __('Select File to Import'),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'input-file'
        ]
    );


    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

/**
 * Return array stores.
 *
 * @return array
 */
private function getStoreData(){
    $storeManagerDataList = $this->storeManager->getStores();
    $options = array();

    foreach ($storeManagerDataList as $key => $value) {
        $options[] = ['value' => $key, 'label' => $value['code'].' - '.$value['name']];
    }
    return $options;
}
}
```

Thank you !